# How to get user info in FirebaseDatabase when user successfully sign in with google?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to get user info in my FirebaseDatabse when user successfully signin with google below are my code:

```
@Override
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
 data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 // Result returned from launching the Intent from 
 GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
 if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
 // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need 
 to attach
 // a listener.
 Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = 
 GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
  try {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = 
   task.getResult(ApiException.class);
      fireBaseAuthWithGoogle(acct);

      } catch (ApiException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "" + e.getMessage(), 
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
  }

  private void fireBaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
  AuthCredential credential = 
  GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
  mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
   .addOnCompleteListener(this, task -> {
     if (task.isSuccessful()) {
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();                   
  DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(user.getUid());
                    HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
                    hashMap.put("username", user.getDisplayName());
                    hashMap.put("uid", user.getUid());
                    hashMap.put("profile", user.getPhotoUrl());

                    reference.push().setValue(reference);
                    //go to HomeActivity
                    startActivity(new 
              Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity2.class));

                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Failed...", 
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
        //show error here
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
 }
 }
```

I want to store in realtime database like 
Users
  username:
  uid:
  profile:
If you teach me how to do this I will also help other when they need help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using this!

```
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    if (user != null) {
                        String name = user.getDisplayName();
                        Uri photo = user.getPhotoUrl();
                        String uid = user.getUid();

                        DatabaseReference reference = 
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(uid);
                        HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
                        hashMap.put("username", name);
                        hashMap.put("profile", "");
                        hashMap.put("uid", uid);

                        reference.setValue(hashMap);

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first add this`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'`
 to your `gradle file`

after that in your activity

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Name, email
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    String email = user.getEmail();
DatabaseReference  usersref,idref,nameref,emailref;
          usersref = rootref.child("USERS");
         idref = users.child(id);
         nameref = idref.child("USER NAME");
         emailref = idref.child("EMAIL");
        nameref.setValue(name);
        emailref.setValue(email);
}
```

Your database nearly looks likes this
[image: Your database nearly looks likes this]

Comment: Thanks! I make different way by using your idea! check my answer!